# Setting up numeric boundaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble setting up a simple boundary.

I've set up a minimum and maximum boundary using this code here.

```
def min3(n,m,o):
    if (n<m<o or n<o<m):
        return(m)
    elif (o<m<n or o<n<m):
        return(o)

def max3(n,m,o):
    if (n>m>o or n>o>m):
        return(n)
    elif (m>n>o or m>o>n):
        return(m)
    elif (o>m>n or o>n>m):
        return(o)
```

This code does not print any values onto my terminal, but if I use:

```
def min3(n,m,o):
    if (n<m<o or n<o<m):
        return("The minimum value is",n)
```

then the values returned get printed in the terminal as "The minimum value is n", which seems like I'm moving along nicely with the program.

BUT, when I actually enter the boundary code, which is:

```
def Boundaries(a,x,b):
    if (x < a):
        return False
    elif(x >=a and x<= b):
        return True
```

then run the program as usual, python3 complains saying

"unorderable types: int() < tuple()"

and I can't figure out how to either make "x" into a tuple, or make "a" into an integer.

Comment: What are the arguments you're passing to these functions? It would help if you can describe these more. When I run `Boundaries` from terminal, if I send all integer values, I receive either a `True` or `False` output.

Comment: I also receive a `None` type from the second `min3` function, e.g., `print min3(10,5,11)` yields `None`.  It seems perhaps that your logic is not accounting for all possible `else` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems like you have input a tuple a, which means somewhere in your code you have:

```
a = ("something, prob. numbers", )
```

or

```
a = "something",
```

Now, to solve your problem, the most straight forward way is a one line function:

```
def boundaries(a, x, b):
    return a <= x and x <= b
```

If the expression evaluates to be False, we return false. Many programmers usually forget the fact that condition is itself a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work how you expect?

```
def Boundaries(a,x,b):
    return True if a <= x <= b else False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of confusing, why not just use the min and max functions?

```
min(1,2,3) 
> 1

max(1,2,3)
> 3
```

And for your boundaries function

```
def boundaries(a, x, b):
    if a <= x <= b:
         return True
    return False #else
```